# Can't copy file into HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have problem with HDSF.

I can't copy any files into it, but I have ample space in DataNodes?
Maybe I have some bad configuration?

Comment: to get good answers to questions, it's best to be as specific as possible. E.g. what exactly did you try, which commands did you run, what was the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should provide specific details like the exception you get, steps you follow etc, Since you have not specified any information at all, i would say check for the config files to make sure you have all the required entries in corresponding files :

In core-site.xml you should have

```
<configuration>
   <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://ipaddress:port</value>
  </property>
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/home/$user/hdfs/tmp</value>
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description>
</property>
</configuration>
```

Similarly hdfs-site.xml should have

```
<configuration>
<property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.data.dir</name>

    <value>/home/$user/hdfs/data</value>
  </property>
<property>
    <name>dfs.name.dir</name>

    <value>/home/$user/hdfs/name</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

And finally the mapred-site.xml should have

```
<configuration>
 <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>ip:port</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's possible that I have not enough RAM memory in DataNode?

Comment: share some details dude., are you getting any exceptions?? We have no clue what you are going through and hence cant comment about RAM.